# AngularJS. Nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-repeat` directive with `ng-repeat-start`/`ng-repeat-end` options. Also inside main loop I have another inner `ng-repeat`. But the problem is that my outer `ng-repeat-start` declaration used just for declaration the loop, actually I'm don't need to repeat the HTML element on which is declared. See example below:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="anArray in arrayOfArrays">  <!-- HOW TO REMOVE THIS EMPTY <tr>? -->

    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="item in anArray ">
        <td>{{item .name}}</span></td>
        <td>{{item .surname}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td>
            <span>Total</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How I can remove the `<tr>` element but preserve the loop declaration?

I tried to declare both loop (outer and inner) on same `<tr>` element, but it doesn't work:

```
  <tr ng-repeat-start="anArray in arrayOfArrays" ng-repeat="item in anArray ">          
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to repeat **everything in the outer loop** you can use the `<tbody>` do the repeat. Code below:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="anArray in arrayOfArrays">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in anArray ">
        <td>{{item .name}}</span></td>
        <td>{{item .surname}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Total</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

If you want to repeat **only the inner loop** multiple times and show the total a single time you might try dividing your table in two elements like:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="anArray in arrayOfArrays">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in anArray ">
        <td>{{item .name}}</span></td>
        <td>{{item .surname}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfooter>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Total</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
</tfooter>
```